# Saving checkbox state from Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have checkbox in my `Recyclerview`, now i am able to click it and show a snackbar. But can anyone help me to save the state of the checkbox from the recyclerview.

I had created an onclicklistener in `onBindViewHolder` of the recyclerview adapter.

```
 private SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            // get the single element from the main array
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mirlogo)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.gallery_no_image)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.gallery_image_fail)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();

            final String images = HomeDataImages.IMAGES[i];
            // Set the values

            ImageLoader.getInstance()
                    .displayImage(images, viewHolder.mImage, options);

             viewHolder.mCheck.setChecked(mCheckedItems.get(i));
        Log.d("Position=", String.valueOf((mCheckedItems.get(i))));

        viewHolder.mCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                mCheckedItems.put(position, isChecked);
                Log.d("Checked Array = ", String.valueOf(mCheckedItems));
//                viewHolder.mCheck.setChecked(mCheckedItems);
//error comes here setChecked(boolean) cannot be applied to SparseBooleanArray
               if (isChecked){
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "Item Favorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();}
                else{
                   Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "Item Unfavorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   snackbar.show();}
               }
            });

    }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `viewHolder.mCheck` is a `CheckedTextView` I would use some like this:

```
private SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    // get the single element from the main array
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mirlogo)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.gallery_no_image)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.gallery_image_fail)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    final String images = HomeDataImages.IMAGES[i];
    // Set the values

    ImageLoader.getInstance()
            .displayImage(images, viewHolder.mImage, options);

    viewHolder.mCheck.setChecked(mCheckedItems.get(i));

    viewHolder.mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            final boolean newValue = !mCheck.isChecked();

            mCheckedItems.put(position, newValue);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(newValue);

            //display the text accordingly with the newValue value
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Item Favorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });

    public List<Integer> getSelectedItemPositions() {
        List<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mCheckedItems.size(); i++) {
            final boolean checked = mCheckedItems.valueAt(i);
            if (checked) {
                selected.add(mCheckedItems.keyAt(i));
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }

    public void restoreSelectedItems(List<Integer> positions){
        for (Integer position : positions) {
            mCheckedItems.put(position, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm using a `SparseBooleanArray` in order to store which elements are checked.

Comment: Now im able to Log all checked and unchecked values. But how can i save that array and restore checked item when app reopens..?? Can u help me please

Comment: I added two methods: one for getting the selected items and one for initialize the selected items array. Once you have the selected items array you can save it in the shared preferences and read it at the Activity startup.