# Making checkbox selected if scan a particular item in Recyclerview android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have got list of data from server in an array and there is a scan button, on scan tap i pass a tag. To all the matching tags, the checkbox should get checked. For now it is checking only last one.

Below is the code

```
 public void checkTag(String tag) {


    for (int i = 0 ;i <receiptList.size();i++)
    {
        if (tagList.get(i).contains(tag))
        {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);

        }
        else
        {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: checkbox only scan the last position and do not maintain selected state

Comment: you have to save checks state in an array. `recyclerView` does not hold checks state by itself . and you have to check or uncheck in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Tried but always setting the last position. Can you please add some snippet ? Please @dariushf

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275556/4936833